# Фильтрация массива по множественным параметрам

Tags: javascript, массивы, ecmascript-6

Делаю фильтрацию масива по чекбоксам и столкнулся с некоторыми сложностямии.  Как отфильтровать массив по значениях из другого массива?

---

Например:есть массив фильтров `filters` по которому должна быть фильтрация.Поле `name` отвечает за имя фильтра,поле `change` отвечает за включена ли фильтрация по этому параметру или нет, поле `criteria` отвечает по каким параметрам нужна фильтрация, например в объекте дожно быть поле `isWork` со значением `false`.
Как сделать функцию `userFilter`, в таком случае?

```js
let users = [{
    name: 'Oleg',
    isWork: true
  },
  {
    name: 'Sasha',
    isWork: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Stiven',
    isWork: false
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    isWork: false
  },
  {
    name: 'Joe',
    isWork: false
  }
];

let filters = [{
    name: 'leads',
    change: false,
    criteria: {
      column: 'isWork',
      value: true
    }
  },
  {
    name: 'jobs',
    change: true,
    criteria: {
      column: 'isWork',
      value: false
    }
  }
];

function userFilter() {
  let newArr = [];
  users.forEach(user => {
    filters.forEach(filter => {
      if (!filter.change) {
        if (user.isWork === filter.criteria.value) {
          newArr.push(user);
        }
      }
    })
  })

  return newArr;
}

console.log(userFilter());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let users = [
  { name: 'Oleg', isWork: true },
  { name: 'Sasha', isWork: false },
  { name: 'Stiven', isWork: false },
  { name: 'John', isWork: false },
  { name: 'Joe', isWork: false }
];

let filters = [{
    name: 'leads',
    change: false,
    criteria: { column: 'isWork', value: true }
  },
  {
    name: 'jobs',
    change: true,
    criteria: { column: 'isWork', value: false }
  }
];

function userFilter() {
  let newArr = [];
  
  users.forEach(user => {
    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
      if (filters[i].change)
        continue;
      if (user[filters[i].criteria.column] === filters[i].criteria.value) {
        newArr.push(user);
        break;
      }
    }
  });

  return newArr;
}

console.log(userFilter());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(1 != 1)
return
```

и еще до 30 символов

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что Вы хотите сказать? До каких еще 30 символов?

Comment: @JavAs Это SO отказывается публиковать ответ, когда в ответе меньше 30-ти символов ).

Comment: Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования, либо Вы можете оставить комментарий. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы.